# When I changed my parent layout from linear to frame or relative it gives me error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

On my previous xml code my app was running correctly:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="82dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Send" />

          </RelativeLayout>

        <ListView
     android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="380dp" />


     </LinearLayout>
```

Now when I changed my xml ,and now when I make relative layout or frame layout as a parent my app gives me error "unfortunately it is stopped", My new xml is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="86dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:ems="10" />

  </RelativeLayout>

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="372dp" >
  </ListView>

        </FrameLayout>
```

Logcat:

> 08-24 19:08:24.050: E/AndroidRuntime(674):    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:809)
>   08-24 19:08:24.050: E/AndroidRuntime(674):    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:998)
>   08-24 19:08:24.050: E/AndroidRuntime(674):    at
>   android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622) 08-24
>   19:08:24.050: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1330)
>   08-24 19:08:24.050: E/AndroidRuntime(674):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4474) 08-24
>   19:08:24.050: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1928)
>   08-24 19:08:24.050: E/AndroidRuntime(674):    ... 11 more

Comment: Did you change it manually?

Comment: Have you read about frame layout first? Follow the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html I want to know your requirement to use the frame layout here? Post log trace as well.

Comment: Post your logcat error .

Comment: Your layout is working fine in my emulator. May be you doing something wrong in your Java class.

Comment: I have edited my question with complete log cat error detail ,please check,

Comment: @rahulkapoor please check

Comment: @CRUSADER please check

Comment: @JatinMalwal please check

Comment: @AmeerHumza post complete logcat traces, check the error traces which starts like `FATAL EXCEPTION: main`, you know all that red color(error) traces..

Comment: 08-24 20:25:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(9215): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 20:25:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(9215): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{soft.b.peopleassist/soft.b.peopleassist.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class 
@CRUSADER

Comment: OK.....Just paste your java class file here..

Comment: You extending you class with ListActivity ?

Comment: @rahulkapoor when i change my id it says that my project contains error,

Comment: @rahulkapoor i love you :p thanks alot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ListView id, If you Extending ListActivity must specify the keyword android.

```
 <ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="372dp" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: you are saying it right but when I change my id xml gives me error and then my project contains error ! @rahul

Comment: ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Message>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter); 

Check my adapter if you get something from it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Ameer Humza, But I did not get such an error while executing both your xmls.

I think you should try cleaning your project first:
Project > Clean.

or

Restart your Eclipse.

What is the version of your eclipse?